# Inserting elements into a list of elements element

Tags: python

How can I insert the values of the collisions into the results table?
This is what Ive tried doing:

```
for elements in collisions:
    for i in results:
        for j in i:
            results[i][j] = elements


collisions = [26, 12, 16, 17, 12, 16, 14, 8, 4, 2, 8, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]


result = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Want:

```
[[26, 12, 4, 3, 2, 2, 0], [12, 16, 2, 4, 3, 2, 0], [16, 14, 8, 5, 2, 2, 0], [17, 8, 5, 3, 6, 3, 0]]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is unclear what you want. What exactly determines where each element goes in each sublist?

Comment: so every forth element in collisions go into results[x][y]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple method breaking the list into sub-lists.

```
x=0
result = []
collisions = [26, 12, 16, 17, 12, 16, 14, 8, 4, 2, 8, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]
while x < len(collisions)/7:
    sub_list = []
    for i in range(x,len(collisions),4):
        sub_list.append(collisions[i])
    result.append(sub_list)
    x += 1
print collisions
print result 
[26, 12, 16, 17, 12, 16, 14, 8, 4, 2, 8, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[[26, 12, 4, 3, 2, 2, 0], [12, 16, 2, 4, 3, 2, 0], [16, 14, 8, 5, 2, 2, 0], [17, 8, 5, 3, 6, 3, 0]]
```

Note: no error checking